# Why type inference from pointfree source code dysfunctional?

Tags: haskell

To test the `type inference` on Haskell I wrote simple function aliases in `pointfree` style below, then tried to load their source files to `GHCi 7.8.3`. Why was it consequently broken on `add'` and `compare'`?

```
id' = id

GHCi> :t id'
GHCi> id' :: a -> a

add' = (+)

GHCi> :t add'
GHCi> add' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer

compare' = compare

GHCi> type variable is ambiguous
```

It would work well if I had typed them directly on `GHCi` e.g.

```
GHCi> let add' = (+)

GHCi> let compare' = compare
```

or changed the source code to `pointful` style e.g.

```
add' x y = x + y

compare' x y = compare x y
```

**Solution**

Add the directive `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to the affected source files.

Comment: [Monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction)

Comment: It's a shame that it's hard to search for this kind of problem on Stack Overflow, especially considering how many people run into it (http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bhaskell%5d%20monomorphism). You would only know the best keyword (monomorphism) if you already know the solution.

Comment: @DavidYoung: Honestly, this is mostly GHCs fault. Much of this could be avoided if the error message gave you a hint that the MMR could be at fault.